# data integration-, multiple databases, unique incremental SOR_id using talend

Tags: talend, data-integration, tmap

I'm trying to integrate multiple databases using talend and in turn have an SOR_id for each table for auditing purposes. is it possible to map between multiple source tables simultaneously to destination table having an SOR_id which is meant to be auto incremented? Would I have incremental values for each source tables rows

**I have approached this using another way as shown in the image so that my SOR_id can be accounted for.**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by this `Would I have incremental values for each source tables rows`?

Comment: Hi melanie, Thank you for your response. So on talend using the above image, I have also connected it so by the trigger>on component ok from each ourput table to the input table. However, since the sources consist rather similar data, I am aggregating all the data. I wanted to know how I could filter this' something similar to a 'left outer join' where i have the existing data + all the non recurring data if that makes sense.